# Can someone please explain to me how ip addresses work with vpn?

Tags: networking, vpn, ip

Recently I've been wondering how the ip's of a vpn work . Are they recycled? If yes isn't issue using them?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do the IP addresses of a VPN work?

> Every internet connection (like your cable modem) is assigned a unique set of numbers called an IP address, which is tied to information such as geographic location, ISP, etc. A VPN replaces your actual IP address to make it look like you’ve connected to the internet from a different location: the physical location of the VPN server, rather than your real location.

Source: [What is a VPN and Can it Hide My IP Address? | McAfee](https://www.mcafee.com/learn/what-is-a-vpn-and-can-it-hide-my-ip-address/)

---

#### Are They Recycled?

It depends. Some VPNs use shared IP addresses, others use dedicated IP addresses

> **Shared IP**
>
> Most VPNs use shared IP’s. This means multiple users (sometimes 100+)
> will be sharing the exact same IP address. This increases user privacy
> (it’s very difficult to identify a specific user by their assigned IP)
> but can cause some issues like the bad neighbor effect, or potential
> even security risks (if the VPN is poorly configured).
>
> **Dedicated IP**
>
> A dedicated IP address is a a static IP address assigned to 1 single
> customer. Because each IP address costs the VPN money, dedicated IP’s
> tend to be much more expensive (2-5x) of a shared VPN service. The
> advantage is, you don’t have to share your IP with anyone so security
> risks are very low. On the downside, privacy is reduced because the
> dedicated VPN address can identify 1 specific user, you.
>
> **Bad Neighbor Effect**
>
> If someone sharing the same IP address with you is abusing a service
> (like google) or sending Spam emails, you may be blocked, slowed, or
> Captcha’d by popular websites.
>
> [image]
>
> This is the bad neighbor effect in action. Usually it’s cause by one
> of two things:
>
> - There are too many users sharing your current IP trying to use google simultaneously (so it looks like spam)
> - The IP address has been blacklisted for past activity
>
> This is an unfortunate side effect of shared VPN IP addresses, and in
> some cases may even cause you to get blocked by a website altogether
> if they have very strict security/antispam settings. The only solution
> in this case is to reconnect the VPN (ideally a different server) in
> the hopes of being assigned an IP that isn’t blacklisted.

Source: [Shared vs. Dedicated VPN IP addresses (Which one is best for you?)](https://www.vpnuniversity.com/learn/shared-vs-dedicated-vpn-ip-address)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation but can you elaborate more on what exactly you meant with "security risks"? . 
Also, what if person A got the same ip assigned in vpn as person B? The one does a good use of it (lets say person A) and the other don't (lets say person B) ? Is person A at any risk?

Comment: I've added some more info to the answer.

Comment: Thank you but again . What if the ip assigned to someone(A) is blacklisted because someone(B) else's before haven't done the right use of it ( for example phishing ) ?
Is A going to have issues due B's activity?
Also, Is it possible the same ip address be used by multiple users at the same time?
Thank you again

Comment: "Is it possible the same ip address be used by multiple users at the same time? Yes. It already says that in the answer.

Comment: "Is A going to have issues due B's activity?" Yes. Again it already says that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer here - it totally depends on the type, purpose and VPN provider.

At its heart a VPN is a virtual connection laid on top of another connection - and at an overview level can be treated the same way.

Thus an IP can be anything from a NAT'd IP to a dynamic world reachable IP assigned out a pool to a static IP to a whole subnet.

There may or may not be reputational issues with a VPB, again depending on its prior use, provider, location and reverse DNS.